# My jsp page only executes the else statement

Tags: java, jsp, if-statement

I have the following login codes.

```
if (uname == "Abigail" && password=="Abby14"){
    response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/Practical_4/member.jsp");
     }

 else {
   response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/Practical_4/index.html");

 }
```

I realized that my jsp page treats the if-statement as if it's an else statement, and only executes the else-statement.

Comment: @WhatIsThatException why equalsIgnoreCase?

Answer (score 1):

What you do is comparing addresses where strings are stored and not the strings them selfs in some case java will store same string in same address but you cannot count on that.Here is a code example that should explain the issue

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    String a = "a";
    String b = new String("a");
    String c = "a";
    System.out.println(a==b); // false
    System.out.println(a==c); //true
    System.out.println(a.equals(b)); // true
}
```

So the buttom line always use equals insterad of ==

Answer (score 0):

Use `equals` for string comparison.

```
 if (uname.equals("Abigail") && password.equals("Abby14")){
        response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/Practical_4/member.jsp");
         }

     else {
       response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/Practical_4/index.html");

     }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

change to use equals and change to order to prevent null pointer

```
if ("Abigail".equals(uname) && "Abby14".equals(password)) {
```